# Angular have an element show up when not in a angular template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an input box with a class directive on it.  Within the input box delement, I want to have another element with an ng-show.  How do I make it so that a scope variable is available on the inner element?

```
<div class="medium-2">
   <label>Age:</label> 
</div>
<div class="medium-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control pop-up-variables" name="age" error-message="ageErrorMessage" required>
   </input>
</div>
```

The block I want to be able to add is this:

```
<input ng-show="showInnerBlock" class="variable-dropdown" type="text" uib-typeahead="number as number for number in numbers | filter:$viewValue" ng-model="selectedAttribute" placeholder="Choose variable"> 
</input>
```

I don't want to return it as a template in the directive because I dont want to replace the block that the directive is on, but I don't know how to add it correctly to the DOM.

The simple JS looks like:

```
  app.directive('popUpVariables', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'];
        },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        element.on('keypress', function(event) {
          if (event.which === 64) {
            // This is where I want to show the second input
            scope.showInnerBlock = true;
          }
        });
      }
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Events outside of angular context that chnge scope must notify angular to run  digest to update view.

if you used `ng-keypress` it would do it internally otherwise use `$apply` or `$timeout`

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
    element.on('keypress', function(event) {
      if (event.which === 64) {            
        scope.showInnerBlock = true;
        $scope.$apply()
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: hey Charlietfl that still isn't working.  Is this possible angular:

      <div class="angularDirective"> 
            <div ng-show="variable"> 
                  Inner element have access to scope?
            </div>
      </div>

Comment: likely running into issues with isolated scope on typeahead directive. your UI is complicated doing so much on that one input... a plunker demo would really help

Comment: Thanks!  It is an isoloate scope issue as when I commented out the scope in the return in my code it worked.  (I tried to just put a simple version on to make it more readable).


So I guess the next question is how would I be able to use an isolated scope but still pass out the correct value of scope.showBlock at that time?   I would assume '=' would do it but it didnt